# C# Linq where clause as a variable

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I am trying to make a LINQ statement where the where clause comes from a variable. For example:

```
string whereClause = address.zip == 23456;
var x = from something in someList where whereClause;
```

Is this possible? I cannot seem to get it to work.

thanks,

Update - my where clause is predefined and will be based on user input so I don't think this will work for me. Basically whereClause is not constructed in the method, it is a parameter of the method which does the LINQ. I didn't explain that well here is a better example:

```
public void doLnq(string whereClause)
{
   var x = from something in someList where whereClause;
   dowork(x);
}
```

Update - Just to sum up some of the suggestions and centralize everything.

I cannot use a switch to generate the where clause because there are way to many possibilities.

The dynamic linq post that a few of you have posted does look promising but i am having trouble related the linq to sql example to my linq to objects problem.

and @sLaks after looking through msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353734.aspx I am having trouble figuring out where you meant to use AsQueryable

thanks,

Comment: Er, no. The where clause is just *not* a string, it's an expression that returns a boolean. Except... see SLaks's link!

Comment: @sq33G the string in this situation would be "address.zip == 23456" I would like to use at as the expression. The string comes from user input so they can do custom searches. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm guessing that the user is choosing the field (field == value) from a dropdown. So you can probably use a switch statement to build a Func<YourType, bool> to send as a Where delegate.

Comment: Yes and No. Yes that is how the string is defined, but the value portion is custom text so only one side of the statement is controllable.

Comment: That's fine, you can make your Where with that: something => something./*field*/ == inputString

Comment: the field portion must be hard coded though and with over 100 possibilities that switch statement is not practical. I should have mentioned that above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6361/discussion-between-sq33g-and-kds6253)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You need to assembly an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` and pass it to the `Where()` extension method:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereClause = a => a.zip == 23456;
var x = frSomeList.Where(whereClause);
```

**EDIT**: If you're using LINQ to Objects, remove the word `Expression` to create an ordinary delegate.

Comment: With a `linq-to-objects` tag, would an *Expression* be appropriate?

Comment: @kds6253: Then you can take a delegate as a parameter.  If you need to use a string, you can use dynamic LINQ (but it will be slower)

Comment: speed shouldn't be an issue, they will be relatively simple queries. Would you happen to have a short example of dynamic linq

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: please refer to my comment on the similar answer below. thanks.

Comment: @kds6253: Just call `AsQueryable()`

Comment: this solution works. Thanks to @sq33G for helping out as well.

Comment: @SLaks That for that. `T` is used to qualify the expression that's being created, but what does the `bool` mean exactly ?

Comment: @FrancisDucharme: Wrong.  `T` and `bool` are the type parameters of the `Func<,>` delegate.  `T` is the parameter type; `bool` is the return type.  (see the delegate declaration)

Comment: guys if whereClause  take two parameters, how to use it in where clause
@SLaks

Comment: @asemmokllati: Your question makes no sense.  `Where()` only passes one parameter (unless you mean the index, in which case just make an expression that takes two parameters).

Answer (score 11):

This:

```
var query = from something in someList where whereClause;
```

is shorthand for:

```
var query = someList.Where(something => whereClause);
```

Assuming `someList` is an `IEnumerable<Address>`, `Where` refers to the [Enumerable.Where Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx). This method expects a `Func<Address, bool>` which you can define as follows:

```
Func<Address, bool> whereClause = address => address.Zip == 23456;
var query = someList.Where(whereClause);
```

Comment: How could it be used in non-lambda form?
when I use this form:
var query = from something in someList where whereClause;
it says it expects a bool.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As Richard has pointed out, the Dynamic Query Library can be used to build dynamic filter expressions. When using Linq-To-Objects make sure to convert your `IEnumerable<T>` to a `IQueryable<T>` first. Here is an (incomplete) example:

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;

namespace System.Linq.Dynamic
{
  public class Example
  {
   // Assuming some value is assigned to below field somewhere... 
   private IEnumerable<Address> m_Addresses;

   public void FilterByZipCode(string zipCode)
   {
      var x = m_Addresses.AsQueryable().Where("Zip == @0", zipCode);
      dowork(x);
   }
  }

  public class Address
  {  
     public String Zip { get; set; }

     // More Properties...  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a built-in Feature of LINQ. Just use the Where extension method.

See [LINQ Query Syntax versus Method Syntax (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Can try:

```
var lstQ_Buffer = new List<Q_Buffer>();
```

Get

```
lstQ_Buffer = unitOfWork.Q_BufferRepository.Get().ToList();
```

Then apply where

```
if (lstQ_Buffer.Count > 0)
{
    lstQ_Buffer = lstQ_Buffer.Where(q => q.fkProgramId == programId && q.fkYearId == yearId && q.fkSemesterId == semesterId && q.fkCourse_ModuleId == courseModuleId && q.fkSubject_SpecialtyId == subjectSpecialtyId && q.fkSubSpecialtyId == subSpecialtyId && q.fkTopicId == topicId && q.fkSubTopicId == subTopicId && q.fkDifficultyLevelId == diffucultyLevelId).ToList();
}
```