# Generic Entity Framework Read Method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, methods, entity-framework-6

I'm new to Entity Framework and would like some help with my Read Methods.

I have this `User` class and its `UserDAO` with my methods.

I´ve already created

```
public IList<User> ReadUsersByName(string _name) {

var search = from m in context.Users
             where m.Name.Contains(_name)
             select m;

IList<User> _users = search.ToList();
return _users;
}
```

to search for Users by their name.

Other than Name, my Users have other attributes that I´d like to seach for (like their Age for example).

Do I need to replicate most of this code just changing "Name" for "Age"?

I´d like to create only one method and pass the Search Value AND Search Field by param. Is it possible?

Comment: You could make a method that uses reflection that takes the property name and search value in as parameters.

Comment: Nice. How do I do that?

Comment: Side note: Entity Framework and DAO is an awkward combination.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass where clauses into functions:

See this answer: [C# Linq where clause as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718480/c-sharp-linq-where-clause-as-a-variable)

So, you could write something like this:

```
public IList<User> ReadUsersWhere(Expression<Func<User, bool>> whereClause) {
  return context.Users.Where(whereClause).ToList();
}
```

And you'd call it like this:

```
foo.ReadUsersWhere(u => u.Name.Contains("Joe"));
```

But at that point, you're basically just exposing an IQueriable/reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly what I was looking for.