# Common expression function for same where condition at different level navigation properties in linq query

Tags: c#, linq, expression

Say I have a database entities structure like this

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual Child Child { get; set;}
}

public class Child
{
    public string Property_1 { get; set; }
}
```

Now say I have two linq queries like this

```
var children = _context.Child.Where(c => c.Property_1 == "X").ToList();
var parents = _context.Parent.Where(p => p.Child.Property_1 == "X").ToList();
```

The where condition in both the cases are in once sense exactly same.

Now I can put the first condition in a separate function which will return `expression` and then I can use it whenever I want to select child with this condition.

But even though the second condition while selecting parent is also same but I will still not be able to use the same expression function for the where clause because it will accept the object of type `Child`.

So my question is, is there any possibility to put the where condition in a separate function in such a way that it can be used with both the linq queries?

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8718480/1136044) is most likely related to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) for such task, which can expand reusable methods.

```cs
public static class QueryExtensions
{
    [Expandable(nameof(IsXValueImpl))]
    public static bool IsXValue(this Child child)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private static Expression<Func<Cahild, bool>> IsXValueImpl()
    {
        return child => child.Property_1 == "X";
    }
}
```

And usage:

```cs
var children = _context.Child.Where(c => c.IsXValue()).ToList();
var parents = _context.Parent.Where(p => p.Child.IsXValue()).ToList();
```

LINQKit can be activated during options building:

```cs
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    .WithExpressionExpanding(); // enabling LINQKit extension
```

Or by `AsExpandable()` extension:

```cs
var children = _context.Child.AsExpandable().Where(c => c.IsXValue()).ToList();
var parents = _context.Parent.AsExpandable().Where(p => p.Child.IsXValue()).ToList();
```

Comment: I do not want to use external library. Isn't there any other way without using the external library?

Comment: Only in case if you repeat such functionality. You have to expand expression and inject into original Expression Tree.

Comment: EF Core itself too clumsy when querying data, that's why there are a lot of extensions. I know at least three third party libraries which do the same thing.