# How Can I write Extension Methods to Simplify a LINQ to Entities Query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

This code is just a random example:

```
var query = _context.Subscriptions
    .Where(s =>
        s.Archived == false &&
        s.Deleted == false &&
        s.FeatureFlag.Archived == false &&
        s.FeatureFlag.Deleted == false &&
        (s.Subscriber.ToUpper() == memberUrl ||
            s.Subscriber.ToUpper() == tenant ||
            userRegions.Contains(s.Subscriber.ToUpper())))
    .Select(s => /* ... */);
```

I'd like to refactor this to make the code more readable (and DRYer), by adding some extension methods to my Models; something like:

```
var query = _context.Subscriptions
    .Where(subscription =>
        subscription.IsActive() && 
        subscription.ApplysToAnyOf(memberUrl, tenant, userRegions))
    .Select(s =>  /* ... */);
```

but since this is LINQ to Entities, it doesn't know how to parse my refactoring, and I'm not fluent enough with LINQ to understand the right way to do it.

Comment: @John Wu, yes there are duplicates, but not answer that you have chosen. Consider to reopen.

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70120616/10646316). IOW, without third party extensions it is not possible. `ApplysToAnyOf` - another pain...